# How to count total amount of "commas" before the first digit in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a string column1. Now, I want to create a second column which counts the number of commas until the first digit appears.

For example, we have [,,4,] then there are 2 commas before the first digit (4) appears. So outcome would be 2. See table below.

```
Column1 Desired Output Digit
[,,4,]  2              4   
[2,,,]  0              2
```

I am using Redshift SQL.

Comment: What engine are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? etc. Please update your tags.

Comment: @GRIV Redshift SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_INSTR` to find the position of the first digit, then take a substring up to that position and use `REGEXP_COUNT` to count the commas.

(untested)

```
REGEXP_COUNT(
  LEFT(Column1, REGEXP_INSTR(Column1, '[[:digit:]]')),
',')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `LTRIM` and `LEN`

`SELECT LEN(Column1) - LEN(LTRIM(Column1, ','))`

Basically this says take the length of the whole string minus the length of the string stripped of leading commas. The difference is the number of commas stripped.

Comment: Specs don't say that there are only commas prior to the first digit. Under the specs given, the string might be `[,,4,]` in which case there are 2 commas before the first digit, but the difference between LEN and comma-trimmed LEN is 0.